# GitHub Pages - CSS is incorrect on live site, fine on local host

Tags: css, github-pages

My github pages site works perfectly fine on my local host, but for some strange reason the css does not show on my live site. I've included images of the issue. I can't debug this on my localhost since it works perfectly fine on there, so I'm constantly reverting and pushing to debug this.

Has anyone encountered this issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKTdl.jpg

Comment: Can you give an example of CSS syntax that works on your local site, but not on the live site? I'm assuming the live site is http://victorzohni.com/?

Comment: Here is the example for the body

    body { 
 background: #ffffff; 
 margin: 0; 
 height: 100%; 
 color: {{ site.colors.secondary }};
 font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 400;
 }'

Comment: I'm not seeing that in the stylesheet at http://victorzohni.com/assets/css/style.css maybe try re-uploading?

Comment: For some strange reason, My live site is pointing to that "normalize.css" when it should be pointing to my proper css file like my local does. I will try to do another push.

Comment: I've done another push, and nothing has changed. My site still points to that normalize.css which is not my css file.

Comment: From what I can tell. My live site is somehow not able to obtain the style.css file, and is instead using a default css

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found the answer. There were two things missing in my files and according to your post at least one of them is missing in yours:

1. Sass assets files must start with two lines of triple dashes (see jekyll docs [here](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/assets/)).
2. Apparently when referencing stylesheets in GitHub Pages you need to reference a specific version of the file. I found the following snippet in [The Minimal Theme](https://github.com/pages-themes/minimal) default layout [source](https://github.com/pages-themes/minimal/blob/master/_layouts/default.html):

   ```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ '/assets/css/style.css?v=' | append: site.github.build_revision | relative_url }}">
   ```